# rendering nested keys in a template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

i have a grouped array that i want to render on the front end via PUG and it's proving a little tricky

here's the array

```
{
    "Apr 14th 19": {
        "5:00 PM": [
            {
                "name": "John",
                "message": "Hey there"
            },
            {
                "name": "Josh",
                "message": "Hey"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Apr 15th 19": {
        "5:00 PM": [
            {
                "name": "Jake",
                "message": "Hey you"
            }
        ]
    }
    }
```

here is my pug code that im trying to use to render the kind of template i want (desired output below)

```
each day in Data
    each hour in day
        each entry in hour
            h2= "The date is" + Object.keys(day)
            h2= "The time is" + Object.keys(hour)
            h2= "The message is" + entry.message
```

the kind of template output i want

```
The date is Apr 14th 19
The time is 5:00 pm
The message is : Hey
The message is : Hey you
(Both messages here because those are 2 nested under under the times)
```

none of this actually works, i can really use some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do something along these lines within your Pug template:

```
each dayObj, day in Data
    h2= "The date is " + day
    each hourObj, hour in dayObj
        h2= "The time is " + hour
        each entry in hourObj
            h2= "The message is : " + entry.message
```

Here's a working Pen: https://codepen.io/chanceaclark/pen/JVpmMd

Comment: works perfectly, one question though  - adding Obj after 'day' gives access to the key itself?

Comment: https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

In the examples under the Pug Iteration section, it shows that the value is the first item and the index/key is the second variable. You were only using the value which was the nested object instead of the index/key of the object. I just renamed the first variable and added the index/key as the name you had.